# Importing and using audio in react.js

Tags: reactjs, import, react-hooks, requirejs, html5-audio

I am trying to create a useAudio custom hook that will be used by a sound effect button in my app.

I've written it like this:

```
import { useMemo, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// import rain from 'assets/audio/rain.mp3'; --> hardcoded import I've tried

const useAudio = (url) => {
  const audio = useMemo(() => new Audio(url), [url]);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.loop = true;
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }, [playing, audio]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

export default useAudio;
```

Then I used it like this to try and make it reusable from the outside:

```
const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(
    require(`assets/audio/${props.audio}.mp3`)
  );
```

Both sending it with the naked path or inside require() gives this error back:

```
"Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace"
    
"useAudio.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources."
```

Then I tried using a hardcoded file import inside the hook and it does work. Any idea how I could write it in a reusable way? I can't think of a way to make the imports dynamic.

Also would love to learn what's the difference between a path reference, require() and import, and why react works this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass relative paths to Audio api in javascript.
try it like this

```js
const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(
    `assets/audio/${props.audio}.mp3`
  );
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: this was the first thing I've tried, it doesn't work. Both this approach and require() gives this error back:

"Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace"
    
useAudio.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work! After browsing a lot of posts here, I came across adding '.default' to the require function like so:

```
const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(
    require(`assets/audio/${props.audio}.mp3`).default
  );
```